# Change wordpress permalink structure for pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

okay, I have 3 sections to a site

/section-1/ 
/section-2/ 
/section-3/

I don't want their child pages to have a reference to them in their permalinks

/section-1/apple/ 
/section-1/orange/ 
/section-1/banana/

The second level pages in each section will never have the same slug or title.
I want the second level pages to look like this in their url:

/apple/
/orange/ 
/banana/

How do I do this? Happy to work in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

On your admin dashboard, under Settings -> Permalinks, you can choose a custom structure for permalinks, I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: No, Locke, this isn't what I'm looking for. This only allows me to change postname, date etc. What I need here is much more advanced. I need to stop child pages inheriting their parent page slugs in their permalinks. That's not covered on that admin page.